# How to change action bar title color when i am using theme "android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light"

Tags: xamarin

How to change action bar title color when i am using theme `android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light` in mono.android.

Answer (score 0):

In your styles

```
<style name="CustomThemeActionBar" parent="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light">
 <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomThemeActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
```

```
 <style name="CustomThemeActionBarTitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:textStyle" >bold</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
```

This is how i was able to change the colour of the text in the action bar

Comment: this issue has been resolve when using like: android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo"